# How to create global obects in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, global-variables

I'm using visual studio 2015.

I'm clearly missing some things...

I want to create a global filestream and stream writer.

```
        Dim wFile As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream _
                  ("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SummitMap1Local\Labels\BufferedData.txt", FileMode.Append)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(wFile)
```

This works fine.  BUT I need to access it globally.  Ideally the code would be in its own .aspx file and the wFile and sw objects could be used in a different .aspx file.

Thanks

(odd that I need to edit my original post to add new info)
I am now trying to add a class based on info from MSDN.  It's not working.  Code -

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text

    Public Class test
        Public Shared Sub CreateFileStream()      
            Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SummitMap1Local\Labels\BufferedData.txt", FileMode.Append
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Then trying to use the class in a function -

```
Protected Function bufferList(ByVal testData As String) As String
    Try
            Dim sw As New StreamWriter(fs)
            sw.WriteLine(testData)
    End Try
End Function
```

I get an error on 'Dim sw As New StreamWriter(fs)' *fs is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level*

I've tried calling it with test.fs, but test does not have an fs property.

Comment: I don't know your motives, but this is a wrong idea. Do not keep this kind of resources global. Create them when you need them, use and dispose.

Comment: @Steve is correct. It would probably be a good idea to create a `Module` or `Class` to encapsulate whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited my original post